# Remove App Bar Title from Navigation Drawer in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, navigation-drawer

I have created a Navigation Drawer in Flutter.

Source available here - https://github.com/deadcoder0904/flutter_navigation_drawer

It looks like this -

## First Screen

[image]

When I click the button, it goes to

## Second Screen

[image]

When I click the button, it goes to

## Tabs Screen

[image]

When I click the hamburger icon on `First Screen`, it goes to

## Drawer Screen

[image]

Now when I click on the 2nd List Item on Drawer Screen, I get the Second Screen like this

[image]

#### Relevant code is in [navigation_drawer.dart](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/flutter_navigation_drawer/blob/master/lib/navigation_drawer.dart) which looks like -

```
class NavigationDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  _NavigationDrawerState createState() => _NavigationDrawerState();
}

class _NavigationDrawerState extends State<NavigationDrawer> {
  int _selectionIndex = 0;
  final drawerItems = [
    DrawerItem("First Screen", Icons.looks_one),
    DrawerItem("Second Screen", Icons.looks_two),
    DrawerItem("Tabs", Icons.tab),
  ];

  _getDrawerItemScreen(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 1:
        return SecondScreen();
      case 2:
        return Tabs();
      default:
        return FirstScreen();
    }
  }

  _onSelectItem(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectionIndex = index;
      _getDrawerItemScreen(_selectionIndex);
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> drawerOptions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < drawerItems.length; i++) {
      var d = drawerItems[i];
      drawerOptions.add(ListTile(
        leading: Icon(d.icon),
        title: Text(
          d.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
        ),
        selected: i == _selectionIndex,
        onTap: () => _onSelectItem(i),
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text('Akshay Kadam (A2K)'),
              accountEmail: Text('a2k@gmail.com'),
            ),
            Column(
              children: drawerOptions,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: _getDrawerItemScreen(_selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I get the Second Screen without the `Hamburger Icon` & `First Screen` title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your code to set HomePage

```
body: _getDrawerItemScreen(_selectionIndex),
```

to

```
body: FirstScreen(),
```

Secondly,

```
_onSelectItem(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectionIndex = index;
      _getDrawerItemScreen(_selectionIndex);
    });
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => _getDrawerItemScreen(_selectionIndex),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: it works but it's missing a back button (hamburger one). any idea?

Comment: Means didn't get you? on which screen missing back button?

Comment: After clicking on `Second Screen` or `Tabs` through the Drawer, it doesn't have the back button since its using `pushReplacement`

Comment: Oh yeah! You have to set your drawer *(code)* on each screens that you set in left side drawer.

Comment: Okay so I changed `pushReplacement` to `push` & changed switch..case `default` case to `NavigationDrawer()` & it works perfectly as expected. Thank you so much for helping me out. Editing the post for the final time :)